# php returning an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am scraping a table off another website and have managed to grab the data and it returns it as an array which is fine.

I'm using for to loop through the array and to print the data and the data display. There are three items in a 'row' -

address, band, price

I'm trying to allocate the returned array to those headers so that I can search address and match it to a current address but I can't seem to find the right code for it.

```
include ("simple_html_dom.php");
// Dump contents (without tags) from HTML
$html = file_get_html('http://www.mycounciltax.org.uk/results?postcode=b757ep&search=Search');
$ret = $html->find("td");
$totalret = count($ret);
for ($x = 0; $x <= $totalret; $x++) {
    echo "$ret[$x] $x <br>";
}
```

thats the code and it returns

```
90, REDDICAP HEATH ROAD, SUTTON COLDFIELD, WEST MIDLANDS B75 7EP 0 
D 1 
£1294 2 
92, REDDICAP HEATH ROAD, SUTTON COLDFIELD, WEST MIDLANDS B75 7EP 3 
D 4 
£1294 5 
94, REDDICAP HEATH ROAD, SUTTON COLDFIELD, WEST MIDLANDS B75 7EP 6 
D 7 
£1294 8 
96, REDDICAP HEATH ROAD, SUTTON COLDFIELD, WEST MIDLANDS B75 7EP 9 
D 10 
£1294 11
```

First you have the address, then the band (D) and then the price underneath (the number at the end of each line is $x just for testing purposes)

How would I go about converting that array so that each line (address, band, price) is assigned it's correct titles so that I could search and match the data?

Comment: just out of interest is javascript out of the question for you ?

Comment: I'd like to use php really, javascript is another language to me and tbh i'm no php expert so branching out would probably confuse me more ha.

Comment: I can appreciate that, just JS would definitely be easier for DOM manipulation. Will take a look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will return something like

```
Array (
   [0] => Array
       (
           [address] => 90, REDDICAP HEATH ROAD, SUTTON COLDFIELD, WEST MIDLANDS B75 7EP
           [band] => D
           [price] => £1294
       )
   [1] => Array
       (
           [address] => 92, REDDICAP HEATH ROAD, SUTTON COLDFIELD, WEST MIDLANDS B75 7EP
           [band] => D
           [price] => £1294
       )


$html = file_get_html('http://www.mycounciltax.org.uk/results?postcode=b757ep&search=Search');
$tds = $html->find("td");

$searchTerm = '92, REDDICAP HEATH ROAD, SUTTON COLDFIELD, WEST MIDLANDS B75 7EP';

$searchResults = array();

$properties = array();
$current = 0;


foreach ($tds as $td) {
    $td = trim(strip_tags(trim($td)));
    // or  $td = trim($td->innertext());
    $properties[(int)($current / 3)][] = $td;
    $current++;
}

$keys = array('address', 'band', 'price');
foreach ($properties as &$property) {
    $property = array_combine($keys, $property);
    if ($property['address'] == $searchTerm) {
        $searchResults[] = $property;
    }
}

print_r($properties);
print_r($searchResults);
```

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you.. I have now got it listing the properties, just need to find a way to scan the properties to see if the address is there and then to display the band and price

Comment: do you need help with that part? If you access mycounciltax site very often, you could also save this data in a local database and search it there. It would be faster and more reliable. And from time to time, you can sync the local data with the data from mycounciltax

Comment: each property has a different council tax band. ideally i'd like the property to find it's own band and price (hence using this code) rather than manually entering the band for each property. That's why I used this website as it lists all the bands for the postcode. I'd just then need to find the correct address to find the band and price for it. I can get it showing the number of properties listed (0-23) but trying to display the actual data for each line is proving difficult ha.

Comment: I updated the answer to include a simple search for a property name. But the name needs an exact match

Comment: your a star, thank you so much!! I need to improve my php skills greatly!

Comment: I'm glad it works. if it's what you wanted, you can select the answer, or vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$array = array();
$arrayIndex = 0;
$col = 0;
foreach($ret as $item) {
    $array[$arrayIndex][] = $item;
    $col ++;
    if ($col === 2) {
        $arrayIndex ++;
        $col = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clean line breaks :

```
$html = str_replace("\n",'',$html);
```